NUITKA error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sspilib.raw._text'
When I use from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth and compile it into a windows console program and then run that program I receive this error
nuitka --onefile token_test.py
----------------------

Python 3.10.5  64bit
Python 3.7.8   64bit
Name: Nuitka
Version: 2.1.6
Name: requests-ntlm
Version: 1.2.0

sample code:
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth


import pwinput



def main():
    print("\n┌───────────────────────────────────┐")
    print("│ Please enter your  log-in details │")
    print("└───────────────────────────────────┘")
    print("Username:")
    username = input()
    password = pwinput.pwinput(prompt='Password: ')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main();

Error
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matt_2\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~2\token_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests_ntlm
  File "C:\Users\matt_2\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~2\requests_ntlm\__init__.py", line 1, in <module requests_ntlm>
  File "C:\Users\matt_2\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~2\requests_ntlm\requests_ntlm.py", line 11, in <module requests_ntlm.requests_ntlm>
  File "C:\Users\matt_2\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~2\spnego\__init__.py", line 26, in <module spnego>
  File "C:\Users\matt_2\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~2\spnego\auth.py", line 10, in <module spnego.auth>
  File "C:\Users\matt_2\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~2\spnego\_negotiate.py", line 31, in <module spnego._negotiate>
  File "C:\Users\matt_2\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~2\spnego\_sspi.py", line 39, in <module spnego._sspi>
  File "C:\Users\matt_2\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~2\sspilib\__init__.py", line 6, in <module sspilib>
  File "C:\Users\matt_2\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~2\sspilib\raw\__init__.py", line 8, in <module sspilib.raw>
  File "src\\sspilib\\raw\\_context_attributes.pyx", line 1, in init sspilib.raw._context_attributes
  File "src\\sspilib\\raw\\_security_context.pyx", line 1, in init sspilib.raw._security_context
  File "src\\sspilib\\raw\\_credential.pyx", line 1, in init sspilib.raw._credential
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sspilib.raw._text'*


Pyinstaller had the exact same issue see here
This was fixed in pyinstaller by compiling the exe with --collect-submodules=sspilib
There does not seem to be a similar option with nuitka
I have tried multiple versions of python and had the same results
Pyinstaller works for me at home but I am unable to use that within the office which is why I need nuitka
